# HTML5 canvas globalAlpha not working

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I need create smooth drawing lines with transparent without `clearRect` method i try use: `globalAlpha` and `strokeStyle` with rgba like this:

`ctx.strokeStyle = "rgba( redChannel, greenChannel, blueChannel,` **`AlphaChannel`**`)";`

But did not work both methods. How i can drawing transparent lines without `clearRect` method. While i use `clearRect` before each drawing `globalAlpha` works, but i need that working without it.

my code example:

```js
var el = document.getElementById('c');
var ctx = el.getContext('2d');

ctx.lineWidth = 10;
ctx.lineJoin = ctx.lineCap = 'round';
ctx.globalAlpha = "0.2";
//ctx.strokeStyle = "rgba(255, 0, 0, 150)";
ctx.strokeStyle = "red";

var isDrawing, points = [ ];

el.onmousedown = function(e) {
  isDrawing = true;
  points.push({ x: e.clientX, y: e.clientY });
};

el.onmousemove = function(e) {
  if (!isDrawing) return;

  //ctx.clearRect(0, 0, ctx.canvas.width, ctx.canvas.height);
  points.push({ x: e.clientX, y: e.clientY });

  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.moveTo(points[0].x, points[0].y);
  for (var i = 1; i < points.length; i++) {
    ctx.lineTo(points[i].x, points[i].y);
  }
  ctx.stroke();
  ctx.closePath();
  
};

el.onmouseup = function() {
  isDrawing = false;
  points.length = 0;
};
```

```css
canvas { border: 1px solid #ccc }
```

```html
<canvas id="c" width="500" height="300"></canvas>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are redrawing the entire path every time the mouse moves, so even though the `globalAlpha` value is set to 0.2 the layering effect makes the line appear solid.

**Option 1:**
use `clearRect` to clear the path `onmousemove` then redraw;

**Option 2:**
draw only the last segment of the path, but overlaps are visible:

```js
var el = document.getElementById('c');
var ctx = el.getContext('2d');

ctx.lineWidth = 10;
ctx.lineJoin = ctx.lineCap = 'round';
ctx.globalAlpha = "0.2";
//ctx.strokeStyle = "rgba(255, 0, 0, 150)";
ctx.strokeStyle = "red";

var isDrawing, points = [ ];

el.onmousedown = function(e) {
  isDrawing = true;
  points.push({ x: e.clientX, y: e.clientY });
};

el.onmousemove = function(e) {
  if (!isDrawing) return;

  //ctx.clearRect(0, 0, ctx.canvas.width, ctx.canvas.height);
  points.push({ x: e.clientX, y: e.clientY });

  ctx.beginPath();

  //draw just the last segment
  if(points.length>1) {
      ctx.moveTo(points[points.length-2].x, points[points.length-2].y);
      ctx.lineTo(points[points.length-1].x, points[points.length-1].y);
  }
  ctx.stroke();
  ctx.closePath();
  
};

el.onmouseup = function() {
  isDrawing = false;
  points.length = 0;
};
```

```css
canvas { border: 1px solid #ccc }
```

```html
<canvas id="c" width="500" height="300"></canvas>
```

**Option 3:**
set the opacity of the `canvas` element

```js
var el = document.getElementById('c');
var ctx = el.getContext('2d');

ctx.lineWidth = 10;
ctx.lineJoin = ctx.lineCap = 'round';
//ctx.globalAlpha = "0.2";
//ctx.strokeStyle = "rgba(255, 0, 0, 150)";
ctx.strokeStyle = "red";

var isDrawing, points = [ ];

el.onmousedown = function(e) {
  isDrawing = true;
  points.push({ x: e.clientX, y: e.clientY });
};

el.onmousemove = function(e) {
  if (!isDrawing) return;

  //ctx.clearRect(0, 0, ctx.canvas.width, ctx.canvas.height);
  points.push({ x: e.clientX, y: e.clientY });

  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.moveTo(points[0].x, points[0].y);
  for (var i = 1; i < points.length; i++) {
    ctx.lineTo(points[i].x, points[i].y);
  }
  ctx.stroke();
  ctx.closePath();
  
};

el.onmouseup = function() {
  isDrawing = false;
  points.length = 0;
};
```

```css
canvas { border: 1px solid #ccc; opacity:0.2; }
```

```html
<canvas id="c" width="500" height="300"></canvas>
```

Answer (score 1):

**Option 3**: use two canvas, on main - draw only on mouse release, and on second preview canvas, just show progress, so drawing will be visible even on mouse move. Also for preview canvas we need to do some tricks like clean previous line segment, so everything looks good.

```js
//main canvas
var el = document.getElementById('c');
var ctx = el.getContext('2d');

//preview
var el2 = document.getElementById('c2');
var ctx2 = el2.getContext('2d');

ctx.lineWidth = 10;
ctx2.lineWidth = 10;
ctx.lineJoin = ctx.lineCap = 'round';
ctx2.lineJoin = ctx2.lineCap = 'round';
ctx.strokeStyle = "rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.5)";
ctx2.strokeStyle = "rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.5)";

var isDrawing, points = [ ];

el2.onmousedown = function(e) {
  isDrawing = true;
  points.push({ x: e.clientX, y: e.clientY });
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx2.beginPath();
};

el2.onmousemove = function(e) {
  if (!isDrawing) return;
  points.push({ x: e.clientX, y: e.clientY });

  //draw just the last segment
  if(points.length>1) {
      ctx.moveTo(points[points.length-2].x, points[points.length-2].y);
      ctx.lineTo(points[points.length-1].x, points[points.length-1].y);
      
      //start preview
      ctx2.beginPath();
      //clean from last line
      ctx2.globalCompositeOperation = "destination-out";
      ctx2.strokeStyle = "rgba(255, 0, 0, 1)";
      ctx2.moveTo(points[points.length-2].x, points[points.length-2].y);
      ctx2.lineTo(points[points.length-1].x, points[points.length-1].y);
      ctx2.stroke();
      //rest
      ctx2.strokeStyle = "rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.5)";
      ctx2.globalCompositeOperation = "source-over";
      //draw new line segment
      ctx2.moveTo(points[points.length-2].x, points[points.length-2].y);
      ctx2.lineTo(points[points.length-1].x, points[points.length-1].y);
      ctx2.stroke();
  }
};

el2.onmouseup = function() {
  ctx2.clearRect(0, 0, ctx2.canvas.width, ctx2.canvas.height);
  ctx.stroke();
  isDrawing = false;
  points.length = 0;
};
```

```css
canvas { 
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    position:absolute;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="c" width="500" height="200"></canvas>
<canvas id="c2" width="500" height="200"></canvas>
```

Comment: it's very nice, but while i drawing i see not transparent line. Can i make it transparent too ?

Comment: Yeah it's nice i try to make real time show transparent line without `clearRect` because i have a lot of lines and cannot redrawing on the each `mousemove ` event as well as cannot use canvas style with opacity like show @Ben because previous drawings on the canvas get opacity too..